# OnBackPressed recreates the activity instead of finishing it

Tags: android, onbackpressed

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            searchView.closeSearch();
        } else if (activeFragment != homeFragment) {
            goToHomeFragment();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

In the above code, when reached in else block, the activity recreate itself instead of finishing itself and exit. The hosted activity has 4 fragments but I guess there's nothing to do with the fragments. So any idea about what went wrong? Any Suggestions? Thank you for paying attention.

EDITED : according to Manzurul Hoque Rumi, moveTaskToBack(true) really did the work. Issue Neutralized. I want to thank everyone who has answered my question.

Comment: please remove finish() from else scope

Comment: _super.onBackPressed();_ will finish your activity too. Don't need to write _finish()_ . Just remove it

Comment: I did , but still having the same issue

Comment: whats written in goToHomeFragment method ? and what is activeFragment and homeFragment varaibles?

Comment: @Override
    public void goToHomeFragment() {
        fm.beginTransaction().hide(activeFragment).show(homeFragment).commit();
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
        appBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        activeFragment = homeFragment;
    }

Comment: edit your question and place this content there .

Comment: Just wondering but why do you call `finish()` when you're already calling `super.onBackPressed();`. Don't say because you want to close the current activity.

Comment: check if you are doing the activity intent in onResume() of activity previous to this one. That will create your activity again

Comment: @ZUNJAE I want to finish the activity, but I called only super , it didnt work . so I tried with finish(), it neither did , so I put both

Comment: @VivekMishra I haven't override onResume() so I guess it cant be the cause

Comment: can you post the code from previous activity

Comment: just comment this line 
//super.onBackPressed();
and call finish only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `finish()` and try

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            searchView.closeSearch();
        } else if (activeFragment != homeFragment) {
            goToHomeFragment();
        } else {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or try vice versa.

Comment: of course, I have tried. Still getting the same result ;'(

Comment: add a `Toast` message in else condition to check if you reach there.

Comment: yes, it has reached in the else block , and the activity is recreated

Comment: `moveTaskToBack(true);` Try it in else block

Comment: Glad to hear that! I updated my answer and you can accept it :-)

Comment: and I also removed super , so only moveTaskToBack() did the job done

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add to manifest `android:noHistory="true"` in part of your activity, which you want to close

```
<activity
        android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:noHistory="true"
        />
```

Comment: still the same :'(

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your root activity as a searchable activity you should define its launch mode as singleTop in your manifest.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            searchView.closeSearch();
        } else if (activeFragment != homeFragment) {
            goToHomeFragment();
        } else {

            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your activity is not created more than once, call  only finish() and remove super.onBackPressed()